# more than one build in queue for specific job in jenkins

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have a job which I trigger with parameters from another job using `wget`. each time I give the job different parameter - which `svn` revision to run with.
I don't want to allow concurrent runs of the same job, but I want to allow more than one pending build in the queue for the job.
From what I have tried it didn't work, I see in the queue only one build of the job pending, no matter how many builds I trigger.
Is it possible with any plugin?

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Requests for build of the same job are queued and are not run concurrently.

Comment: I see in the queue only one build of the job pending, no matter how many builds I trigger

Comment: What URL are you passing to wget?

Comment: `http://myhost:8080/job/jnb_nbflow/buildWithParameters?jnb_revision=$SVN_REVISION`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Jenkins doesn't place a build in the queue if it already contains one with the same param values.

To trick it, you could add an additional, unused param, and set it to a random value when calling `wget`.

Comment: Thanks, same when running form Jenkins web UI

Answer (score 7):

I needed to do the same, and discovered the [Random String Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Random+String+Parameter+Plugin). This adds a random string to each build as a parameter, which is enough to make each build unique and for Jenkins to queue them independently rather than coalesce them.

Comment: Do not forget to activate the option 'This project is parameterized' with the 'Ranom String Parameter' to the job configuration