# JIRA Trigger Plugin: One job could not be triggered simultaneously by two Jira issue event

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-jira-trigger

During daily work, I am using JIRA Trigger Plugin to trigger Jenkins job when Jira issue status change. Teammate creates two Jira issues based same issue type, then he change issue status almost at the same time. We can see "Build is scheduled for ..." comment in both issues. But only one Jenkins job build was triggered.

After enable Jenkins logging at FINE level for troubleshooting, log as below:

> Sep 05, 2017 5:16:12 PM WARNING jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn
>   newBuild A new build could not be created in job
>   Jira_Project_Feature_Updator java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   JENKINS-23152:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jira_Project_Feature_Updator/builds/181 already
>   existed; will not overwrite with Jira_Project_Feature_Updator #181    at
>   hudson.model.RunMap.put(RunMap.java:188)  at
>   jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:185)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractProject.newBuild(AbstractProject.java:1019)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:1218)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:145)
>     at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:358)  at
>   hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:340)   at
>   hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1362)     at
>   hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1223)  at
>   hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:340)
>
> Sep 05, 2017 5:16:12 PM SEVERE hudson.model.Executor run Unexpected
>   executor death java.lang.Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   JENKINS-23152:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jira_Project_Feature_Updator/builds/181 already
>   existed; will not overwrite with Jira_Project_Feature_Updator #181    at
>   jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:193)
>     at hudson.model.AbstractProject.newBuild(AbstractProject.java:1019)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:1218)
>     at
>   hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:145)
>     at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:358)  at
>   hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:340)   at
>   hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1362)     at
>   hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1223)  at
>   hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:340) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: JENKINS-23152:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Jira_Project_Feature_Updator/builds/181 already
>   existed; will not overwrite with Jira_Project_Feature_Updator #181    at
>   hudson.model.RunMap.put(RunMap.java:188)  at
>   jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:185)
>     ... 8 more

I simply think it’s because the first change event trigger job build #181, and the second event also want to run build #181, but it's already existed.

I am not sure these result is related to my configuration or the plugin. The plugin works well except this problem.

Below is my version info:

- Jenkins: 2.19.3
- Jira: v6.3.6#6336-sha1:cf1622c
- JIRA Trigger Plugin: 0.4.1 & 0.4.3-SNAPSHOT

I also try the latest plugin release https://ci.jenkins.io/blue/organizations/jenkins/Plugins%2Fjira-trigger-plugin/detail/master/10/artifacts/, but the result is the same.

Comment: Please don't request help from a specific user. **They won't get a notification** if you use their username. If a reader can help you, then they will, no matter who it is. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your advices. First answer in SO, feel good community atmosphere :)

Comment: Sounded like a feature request, you might want to file that to our issue tracker (details documented in the README). Meanwhile, you might want to try this workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24918670/2464295 (I didn't test this).

Comment: Thank you very much @ceilfors. I try the workaround you mentioned, with the Random String Parameter Plugin, multiple Jenkins job builds can be well triggered when Jira issues changing status simultaneously. It's a scene that often appears in our daily work. Thanks to JIRA Trigger Plugin our workflow come true :) Later I will try to file this case in JENKINS issue tracker as a feature request.

Comment: I also encounter another case, I find it already in issue tracker: [JENKINS-43964](http://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-43964), the state is not only "Two Build URLs appearing in JIRA comment", but also two Jenkins job builds with same parameter were triggered. I am not sure what Jira operation cause this happen. It's not show two build URLs in comment at beginning of workflow. But when two URLs commented happen, the situation will continue to occur.

Comment: @truezdg Good to hear that the plugin is useful! :) I don't really understand your last comment, you might want to file another ticket for that with the detailed step to reproduce.