# How can I queue up multiple builds on different commits in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

### Scenario

- A job that takes 12 hours to run: `JOB`
- A few commits on a branch:
  `C0`, `C1`, `C2`, `C3`.

Is it possible to tell Jenkins to run the job on each of those commits in sequence?

### Almost a solution:

Use `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` in the job settings.

You would have to push each commit 1 by 1, and start the job manually after each commit has been pushed. Also this has the behavior of running the builds in parallell which might be unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins by default, the concurrent builds are Turn On - Meaning If you commit to a repository multiple time frequently the configured Jenkins job for that repository will start building parallelly (like below image )

[image]

But If you don't want that behavior, just turn Off the concurrent build

If you are using Jenkinsfile

```
node {
    properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])
    stage('build') {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are using a freestyle job

[image]

After you Turn off the concurrent build, your Job will be queued (like below)

[image]

Comment: Yes, but this is not a solution since it only queues up 1 build, and the commit it will build on is not fixed, so if there are more commits on the branch, it will only build on the latest one.

Comment: you mean to say, you want to queue a number of jobs based on number of commits?

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268753/more-than-one-build-in-queue-for-specific-job-in-jenkins) will help you

Comment: Of course there is a hack to do it ... I would rather not fiddle with that. If I remember corectly, it takes more clicks to start a parameterized job than a job without parameters.