# How to put more than one build into the queue on Jenkins when triggering through script?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Okay, right off the bat I will dispel the initial criticism: I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268753/more-than-one-build-in-queue-for-specific-job-in-jenkins) and tried to implement a solution based on the responses, being very hopeful. However, it didn't fly.

What I'm trying to do is build a CI pipeline that the dev team can trigger at their discretion by means of a python script. That way they can set even some time consuming tests to run without considerable interruption in flow. To this effect we currently have a single pipeline since we're kinda proving this concept, but this problem is stumping me.

Running the script does add a build job (let's call that job job 0), and running it again adds another job into the queue (job 1). However, running the script after *that* does nothing. No further jobs can be enqueued before job 1 is being executed, and no matter what it appears there can only be one running job and one enqueued job.

To achieve the trigger job via script, I'm using [this plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-token-root/) and what my python script ultimately does is form a curl command that has this general form:

```
curl [url to jenkins]/job/[jenkins folder name]/job/[job name]/buildWithParameters?token=[some token]&user=[username]&branch=[branch that the job will pull] . . . &id=[some random uuid as hex string]
```

The actual values are not relevant to the question and are omitted, the ellipses indicate further omitted parameters.

The curl itself does what it is supposed to, in that it triggers a job. After running across the question linked I added the uuid parameter into the curl and it is generated each time the script is run so it has vanishingly low probability of repeating between any two attempts to run it. The parameter itself is received by the parametrized job that has been set up for this, but the job doesn't do anything with this information, it's only to try and get around Jenkins not wanting to enque jobs with identical parameters.

What is going wrong here? How do I get around this problem? Being able to only enqueue a single job screws up the entire use case for the script, as the plan for it was to have a simple, quick and easy to use script that any number of developers can trigger at their leisure, as many times as desired. A form of "push the button, keep writing code, get notified what the tests said later". But if only one job can be enqueued, even a small group of devs will saturate the pipeline to the point that new jobs cannot be enqueued and they would have to go launch the job by themselves in Jenkins GUI which number one, would defeat the purpose of the whole pipeline, and number two, would make access and account management absolute hell.

I would greatly appreciate your aid in this matter.

Comment: You should examine the info that is returned from `curl` call in different cases.

Comment: Make sure there isn't a build queue limit:  Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Build Triggers > Build Queue Limit

Answer (score 0):

The most common (and simplest to use) approach is for each developer to work in their own branch, and a CI job to be a multibranch pipeline that would be triggered on each commit from those developers when there are pull requests from their branches. So I'm not sure why a manual triggering via the Python script is required. However, if you're trying to implement something like [TeamCity's personal builds](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/personal-build.html), I'd understand that.

So to start with, if you happen to use a usual (not a [multibranch](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/) one) pipeline, that's not the best way to set up CI in Jenkins - just set up a multibranch pipeline and you'll see the difference. One of the main reasons is that Jenkins indeed [does not execute more than one pipeline job with identical parameters](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-55748). The second one would be mess in job history after that.

In addition to the build queue limit setting suggested by [@M B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730626/m-b) in comments, there are several more things that could restrict the number of parallel builds:

- [disableConcurrentBuilds](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#available-options) option defined in your pipeline code;
- not enough build agents and/or build executors on those agents;
- your pipelines depend on some [lockable resource](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/#sidebar-content);
- other plugins that affect Jenkins behavior in this regard.